# install php on server08 manaully

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, php

Looking to install php on a 08 box already holding iis/sql box. I've tried the webinstaller a couple times but the installer locks before completion or managing to echo any sort of error message.

Before hunting down a manual install how-to i wonder if the box is trying to tell me something i should be paying attention to. PHP running alongside IIS _must be supported or one would expect that error message to be kinda high on the list.

any gochas to beware of?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowed from iishack.com

1. Install the PHP4 or PHP5 package (32-bit) in C:\PHP or wherever you like. Only use the Windows installer from php.net if you do not need any extensions. I would recommend downloading the PHP zip package.
2. Open the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
3. Double-click “Handler Mappings” from the main IIS screen.
4. Click on “Add Script Map.”
5. Set up the handler mapping for c:\PHP\php5isapi.dll with extension *.php and check to allow the ISAPI extension and execution of scripts.
6. Double-click “ISAPI & CGI Restrictions” on the main IIS screen. Right-click on PHP and select “Edit Feature Settings” and check “Allow unspecified ISAPI modules.”
7. Right-click on the Default Application Pool (or the one you want to use if more than one) and select “Advanced Settings.”
8. Change the “Enable 32-bit Applications” to True. Click OK. This spawns the App Pool in 32-bit mode, so if you have other modules that need to be run in 64-bit mode, best to separate the website into two App Pools: one 32-bit and one 64-bit.
9. Restart the server.